# Accessing a scope attribute in a directive, where the attribute is set via Ajax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, web, frontend

I'm setting a value on `$scope` in an Ajax response function.

```
$http.post('/aUrl', someData)
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.value = response.data;
    });
```

This means it is `undefined` until the `.then` callback runs.

I want to use this value in a custom directive, like so:

```
myModule.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            // do stuff with scope.value...
        }
    };
});
```

In the template:

```
<div my-directive value="value"></div>
```

However when the link function runs, the value is still `undefined`.

What is the proper way to deal with this?

Comment: Can't you make the ajax call inside your directive ?

Comment: would it be helpful if I made a plunker to explain?

Comment: @PatrickLawler It might be, thanks :)

Comment: working on one currently, just reproduced your use case: http://plnkr.co/edit/RVz7ru?p=preview

Comment: if you want a solution that depends on your directive being a sibling to your parent controller, I'd recommend we use a service, or observe the attribute like Aviv recommended. If your directive can be positioned as a child of the parent controller then this method actually works fine and you don't have to change anything, the scope of your directive will share the scope of it's parent

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the value for changes:

```
attributes.$observe('value', function (val) {
    if (val) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I'll try this. By the way, why am I putting `value` in the `scope` if it's already available in the `attributes`?

Comment: the 'value' called by $observe represents $scope.value

Answer (score 0):

The safest solution for accomplishing this is to share the data in a service. I created a plunker to demonstrate.

```
myAppModule.factory("pollingService", function ($http, $timeout, $q) {
  var svc = this;
  svc.data = { resp: {}, count: 0};
  svc.count = 0;

  svc.poller = function() {
    svc.count++;
    return $http.get('data.json').then(function(r) {
      svc.data.count=svc.count;
      //console.log(data);
      $timeout(svc.poller, 4500);
    });
  };

  return svc;

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RVz7ru?p=preview

However, there are MANY ways to accomplish what you are looking to do, I highly recommend following this guide when you are working with Angular. it will keep your code clean, and ready to port to Angular 2 easily.
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: (I got rid of that nasty promise in there before... borrowed the original plunker from another sandbox... should be slightly easier to understand now)